# Completely positive map on C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation in a book about C*-algebra.

A positive linear functional $f$ on an operator system $E$ is completely positive map. Indeed, for $\xi=(\xi_{1}, \xi_{2},\ldots,\xi_{n})\in l_{n}^{2}$ (here, $l_{n}^{2}$ denotes $n$-dimensional Hilbert space) and $a=[a_{i, j}] \geq 0$ in $M_{n}(E)$, we have

$$\langle f_{n}(a)\xi, \xi\rangle=f(\Sigma_{i,j=1}^{n}\bar{\xi_{i}}\xi_{j}a_{i,j})=f((\bar{\xi_{1}},\ldots,\bar{\xi_{n}}) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & \cdots &a_{1n}\\
      \vdots &  &  \vdots\\
    a_{n1}& \cdots &a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right)
) \geq 0$$

I do not know why this $f((\bar{\xi_{1}},\ldots,\bar{\xi_{n}}) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & \cdots &a_{1n}\\
      \vdots &  &  \vdots\\
    a_{n1}& \cdots &a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right)
) \geq 0$ holds? Could someone explain it to me ? Thanks.

Comment: I changed $< f_{n}(a)\xi, \xi >$ to $\langle f_{n}(a)\xi, \xi\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Ok thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(here I'm addressing in part Tom's answer, and a mistake in the question). The vector $\xi$ is not in $l^2_n$; this makes no sense, as we need the operator system $E$ to act on each coordinate. Rather, $\xi\in \oplus_{j=1}^nH$, where $H$ is the Hilbert space such that $E\subset B(H)$. So the (bad) notation in the proof quoted in the question actually means
$$
\bar\xi\,\xi a=\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle, 
$$and
$$
(\bar{\xi_{1}},...,\bar{\xi_{n}}) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & ... &a_{1n}\\
      \vdots &  &  \vdots\\
    a_{n1}& ... &a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right)=\left\langle \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & ... &a_{1n}\\
      \vdots &  &  \vdots\\
    a_{n1}& ... &a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right)
\,\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right)
\right\rangle
$$
Now the positivity of $A$ makes the inner product non-negative.

Comment: @Martin Argerami:But, I suppose, in you equation above, $(\xi_{1},\ldots,\xi_{n}) \left(\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & \cdots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots &  &  \vdots\\
a_{n1}& \cdots &a_{nn}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\xi_{1} \\
\vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right)
$ is an element in operator system $E$

Comment: @Martin Argerami And $\langle \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & \cdots &a_{1n}\\
      \vdots &  &  \vdots\\
    a_{n1}& \cdots &a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \xi_{1} \\
      \vdots \\
    \xi_{n}
  \end{array}\right) \rangle$ is a complex number, So what does your equal sign mean?

Comment: No, the point is that the left-hand-side is (really bad) notation for the right-hand-side.

Comment: @Martin Argerami I am sorry, I can not understand what is "(really bad) notation"?

Comment: Because $\xi_j$ is vector in a Hilbert space.  So there's no obvious meaning for $\bar \xi_j$ nor $\bar\xi_j\,\xi_j$